# C# How test Jetbrains RESTClient with Xunit

Tags: c#, rest, mocking, moq, xunit

Somewhere in my code I do the following code to get the uri in order to log:

```
string uri = restClient.BuildUri(request).ToString();
```

I have some unit tests which have broken because of it, so I tried to mock this doing:

```
    var restClientMock = new Mock<RestClient>();
    restClientMock
        .Setup(client => client.BuildUri(It.IsAny<IRestRequest>()))
        .Returns(new Uri("http://localhost:8080/"))
        .Verifiable();
```

But I receive:

```
  Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: client => client.BuildUri(It.IsAny<IRestRequest>())
```

I am newbie with Xunit and I don`t know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is correct. [`RestClient.BuildUri`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/RestClient.cs#L293)  is a non-virtual member.

```
/// <summary>
///     Assembles URL to call based on parameters, method and resource
/// </summary>
/// <param name="request">RestRequest to execute</param>
/// <returns>Assembled System.Uri</returns>
public Uri BuildUri(IRestRequest request)
{
    DoBuildUriValidations(request);

    var applied = GetUrlSegmentParamsValues(request);

    string mergedUri = MergeBaseUrlAndResource(applied.Uri, applied.Resource);

    string finalUri = ApplyQueryStringParamsValuesToUri(mergedUri, request);

    return new Uri(finalUri);
}
```

Moq is unable to mock non-virtual/abstract members.

Your classes should not be tightly coupled to implementation concerns / concretions, but to abstractions.

In this case you should be using `IRestClient`, which is what `RestClient` is derived from.

This would allow the test to be configured correctly

```
//...

var restClientMock = new Mock<IRestClient>();
restClientMock
    .Setup(client => client.BuildUri(It.IsAny<IRestRequest>()))
    .Returns(new Uri("http://localhost:8080/"))
    .Verifiable();

//...
```